# How to customize the text content of sms sent by deepView desktop in branch

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

I want to customize the text that is being send to the users when they enter their number on deepview web to download the appliation. Is it possible to change that content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex with Branch.io here: you can do this! It's a bit buried on our docs site, but there are two options:

1. Set the content on a link-by-link basis using the `$custom_sms_text` control parameter. Read about it [here](https://dev.branch.io/features/text-me-the-app/advanced/#link-specific-messages).
2. Overwrite for all links using [this Dashboard option](https://dev.branch.io/features/text-me-the-app/advanced/#custom-default-for-all-messages)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Alex.

Comment: Is there a way the custom sms text be set  when actually creating the deep link? I tried putting setting $custom_sms_text in the data section of a link create but noticed it doesn't take.

Comment: @jontyc yes there is! You're doing it right, except $custom_sms_text is a control parameter and so it doesn't go *inside* the data section.